# In "built to last", is "last" a verb or an adjective?

Tags: idioms, parts-of-speech

Up to my best knowledge, the idiom "smth is built to last" means that smth is durable, of high quality and expected to serve for a long time. However, I cannot understand what does the phrase mean literally. I have two guesses.

The first one: "last" is a verb. The builder expects that smth will last (continue its being) for a long time.

The second: "last" is an adjective. Like "built to the very last age". It doesn't look like a grammatically correct sentence to my intuition, though many English idioms do not as well.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression ***"built to last"***, "***last***" is a verb in the infinite form "[to last](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last)". A similar expression, for instance, is:

- born to run.

[Last](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/last) as an adjective would not fit in the sentence.

(M-W, Dictionary.com)